# Java - Drawing with awt-package

Tags: java, awt, graphics2d

```
public class DrawLine extends DrawPanel{
public DrawLine(){}
public void paint (final Graphics g){
    final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    final Line2D aLine = new Line2D.Double(10 , 10 , 70 , 70);
    g2d.draw(aLine);
}
public static void main (final String[] args){
    DrawFrame.display ("DrawLine" , new DrawLine());
}}
```

This is my code, and I'm importing whole java.awt.*-package.
The error message is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
DrawFrame cannot be resolved
    at DrawLine.main(DrawLine.java:11)
```

My IDE is Eclipse, latest version and when doing java -version in cmd I have "1.7.0_02".

Environmentvariables:

Path:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Java Work;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\12.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Roxio\OEM\AudioCore\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;.;
```

Classpath:

```
.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Java Work;.;
```

Simple programs such as input-output, hello world, calculations work. I have tried to make numerous graphical programs and it seems DrawFrame is the problem. Is it some package I am missing? I dont believe its the environmentvars since I can compile other programs - java is so much trouble (I have only programmed in Python & Scheme befor).

Comment: Where did you get `DrawPanel` from?  It seems `DrawFrame` should be in the same API.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use prehistoric Java AWT use [Swing JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) instead.
2. Read [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html), there are examples for similar painting.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson

How come I awt isnt the prefered? 
I am reading 2D Graphic examples from the book "Developing Java Software (3rd ed)" by Russel Winder & Graham Roberts.
The teacher of my course says we should read about java .awt so aslong as JComponents arent identical I need to use it.

Comment: @user1160248  You should direct your comment to mKorbel who answered the question.  I just edited the answer (and up-voted the advice).  ;)

Comment: @user1160248 `aslong as JComponents arent identical` that not true, but if required usage AWT, then use that, read tutorial and to try convert Swing example from tutorial to AWT, remove all J in the imports or JComponent definitions and change method paintComponent() to  paint()

Comment: But for the sake of your fellow students and the industry, please 'smack you teacher upside the head' and tell them that in this millennium there is no sense teaching people how to use AWT *components.*  Much of the AWT is still relevant, but the components are not.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, DrawFrame needs to be implemented manually. But that's not really your problem. I can see you'd like to familiarize yourself with Java and you like doing so through actual code.

Personally, I learned basic AWT/Swing through an Eclipse plugin which generated the code for me. You cand find it [here](http://www.cloudgarden.com/jigloo/). The most important thing you need to learn is the difference between Container and Component and how they add up. Try making a simple Applet with a Panel and a few buttons to see how the code looks. It's relatively easy to evolve from there, because the generated code is very well structured and very intuitive.

I recommend an older version of Eclipse for this plugin - I remember Helios (3.6) did the trick.

Also, if you're new to Java, the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) (or Javadoc) are your best friend. Just Ctrl+F your AWT/Swing element there to see the methods it makes available and what they do.